# Optimizing an Update statement with many records in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, sqlalchemy

I am trying to update many records at a time using SQLAlchemy, but am finding it to be very slow. Is there an optimal way to perform this?

For some reference, I am performing an update on 40,000 records and it took about 1 hour.

Below is the code I am using. The *table_name* refers to the table which is loaded, the *column* is the single column which is to be updated, and the *pairs* refer to the primary key and new value for the column.

```
def update_records(table_name, column, pairs):
    table = Table(table_name, db.MetaData, autoload=True, 
    autoload_with=db.engine)
    conn = db.engine.connect()

    values = []

    for id, value in pairs:
        values.append({'row_id': id, 'match_value': str(value)})

    stmt = table.update().where(table.c.id == bindparam('row_id')).values({column: bindparam('match_value')})
    conn.execute(stmt, values)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing a list of arguments to `execute()` essentially issues 40k individual `UPDATE` statements, which is going to have a lot of overhead.  The solution for this is to increase the number of rows per query. For MySQL, this means inserting into a temp table and then doing an update:

```
# assuming temp table already created
conn.execute(temp_table.insert().values(values))
conn.execute(table.update().values({column: temp_table.c.match_value})
                           .where(table.c.id == temp_table.c.row_id))
```

Or, alternatively, you can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to avoid creating the temp table, but SQLAlchemy does not support that natively, so you'll need to use a custom compiled construct for that (e.g. [this gist](https://gist.github.com/timtadh/7811458)).

Comment: I tried to use the Upsert statement from the link you provided but ran into some issues. I updated conn.execute(stmt, values) to conn.execute(Upsert(stmt)) and got the following exception "sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: FROM expression expected". I will try creating a temp table and inserting from there, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [document fast-execution-helpers](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#psycopg2-fast-execution-helpers), batch update statements can be issued as one statement. In my experiments, this trick reduce update or deletion time from 30 mins to 1 mins.

```
engine = create_engine(
    "postgresql+psycopg2://scott:tiger@host/dbname",
    executemany_mode='values_plus_batch',
    executemany_values_page_size=5000, executemany_batch_page_size=5000)
```